# ForkJoinTask vs CompletableFuture

Tags: java, future, fork-join, forkjoinpool, completable-future

In Java 8 there are two ways of starting asynchronous computations - `CompletableFuture` and `ForkJoinTask`. They both seem fairly similar - the inner classes of `CompletableFuture` even extend `ForkJoinTask`.

Is there a reason to use one over the other?

One key difference that I can see is that the `CompletableFuture.join` method simply blocks until the future is complete (`waitingGet` just spins using a `ManagedBlocker`), whereas a `ForkJoinTask.join` can steal work off the queue to help the task you're joining on to complete.

Is there a benefit over one or the other?

Answer (score 11):

They are two different things, `ForkJoinTask` is a task that can be submitted to a `ForkJoinPool`, `CompletableFuture` is a promise that can work with any `Executor` and the executor doesn't need to be the `ForkJoinPool`,

It is true however that the common `ForkJoinPool` is the default if you don't specify any, for ex:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> supplier);
```

uses the `ForkJoinPool` if you don't pass an `Executor`. There is another `overload` that takes an `Executor`.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> supplier,executor);
```

`Async` ,which is a `static` class in `CompletableFuture` extends `ForkJoinTask<Void>`, but it doesn't need to be a `ForkJoinTask`, from the docs of `Async`

> /** Base class can act as either FJ or plain Runnable */

```
abstract static class Async extends ForkJoinTask<Void>
    implements Runnable, AsynchronousCompletionTask
```

It can also a `Runnable` and a `AsynchronousCompletionTask`

Just on side note: `ForkJoinTask`, `ForkJoinPool`, `ForkJoin...` classes were added in 1.7 and not 1.8

Comment: I suppose my question is more about when you would use one and not the other (assuming you're using the default common FJP). When joining to a CompletableFuture, does it help complete the task you're joining to?

Comment: @thecoop I don't see how u can replace one with  the other, CompletableFuture is a promise that has operation like thenApply and thenCompose, now if your question is when do I use ForkJoinTask? I would say when u writing your own parallel algorithms

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that the `ForkJoinTask` is more recommended when you have a big task and want to split it to run in parallel in several sub tasks. The `ForkJoin` framework uses the work stealing algorithm which will make an efficient use of the threads. On the other hand, `CompletableFutures` are more appropriate for a Reactive programming model, where you can create pipelines of execution in a sync or async fashion, and have a better control of the threads by using the thread pools of the Executor Service.